# Jest cannot find module @env React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I'm currently facing some problem I'm using in my react native app https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv for handling .env.

Error => Cannot find module '@env' from 'src/api/api.ts'

I'm testing currently my redux saga to call the api endpoint:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {API_URL} from '@env';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  responseType: 'json',
});
```

API Endpoint

```
export const sendCheckNumber = async (
  phoneNumber: string,
): Promise<AuthenticationTO> => {
  const response = await axios.get<AuthenticationTO>(
    `SendCheckNumber/${phoneNumber}`,
  );

  return response.data;
};
```

I'm using  ts-jest package.json. I saw in the docs its possible to include bable in ts-jest  because I'm using bable to import the  'module:react-native-dotenv', as plugin. I thought that will already solve my problem but unfortunately it still fails. Maybe someone of you have some suggestion what could cause this error.

Thank you!!!

package.json

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "babelConfig": "babel.config.js",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.jest.json"
      }
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$"
  }
```

Comment: Please update the question with your babel config file (the part where you have used it as plugin)

Answer (score 7):

Maintainer goatandsheep here. I recently added some documentation on how this is done. Take a look at the [documentation section on TypeScript](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/blob/main/README.md#typescript). Here is the excerpt:

> - Create a `types` folder in your project
> - Inside that folder, create a `*.d.ts`file, say, `env.d.ts`
> - in that file, declare a module as the following format:
>
> ```
> declare module '@env' {
>   export const API_BASE: string;
> }
> ```
>
> Add all of your .env variables inside this module.
>
> - Finally, add this folder into the `typeRoots` field in your `tsconfig.json` file:
>
> ```json
> {
>     "typeRoots": ["./src/types"],
> }
> ```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: That did resolve my @env module not found issue. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Implemented the first solution and did not work out I am still getting `Module '"react-native-dotenv"' has no exported member 'API_URL'` .

Comment: @VikrantShah what is your `moduleName` value in your `babel.config.js`?

Comment: @VikrantShah where you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @AndreySolera are you still having issues? I am the maintainer and happy to help.

Comment: This configuration gave me another type of error. If I add the typeRoots with my types folder my Jest types library doesn't work anymore, so all my test are failing :( how can I fix this error? (if I delete the typeRoots everything is back to normal with my tests)

Comment: @cblnpa what error are you seeing?

Comment: @KemalAhmed "Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest`" but if I delete typeRoots from my tsconfig file everything works fine

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem like following.

```
import {API_URL} from '@env';`
```

Added this instead:

```
import {API_URL} from 'react-native-dotenv';
```

And add the next in **babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          moduleName: "react-native-dotenv",
        },
      ],
    ],
  }
}
```

It works well for me.

Comment: Or change your moduleName to '@env'
My problem was moduleName and other things was in quotes like this
module.exports = {
  "plugins": [
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
      "moduleName": "@env",
      "path": ".env",
      "blacklist": null,
      "whitelist": null,
      "safe": false,
      "allowUndefined": true
    }]
  ]
}
I deleted quotes inside object keys and its working rn